# Append one object to another one

Tags: javascript, json

I have two JSON objects, and I want to append `newData` into existingData.

```
existingData = {"School Name" : "Albert"}
newData = {"Teacher Name" : "Ms. Mithcell"}
```

This is the output I want:

```
existingData = {"School Name" : "Albert" , "Teacher Name" : "Ms. Mithcell"};
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you tried to google it? Tip: search for "merge javascript objects".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For javascript its `object` not python like `dictionary` :P, Just use [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) Syntax to get your job done.

```js
existingData = {"School Name" : "Albert"}
newData = {"Teacher Name" : "Ms. Mithcell"}
result = {...existingData, ...newData};
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has the `Object.assign` function.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

```
existingData = {"School Name" : "Albert"}
newData = {"Teacher Name" : "Ms. Mithcell"}

Object.assign(existingData, newData) 

console.log(existingData); // {School Name: "Albert", Teacher Name: "Ms. Mithcell"}
```

Object.assign( originalObject, newObject ) will return originalObject with newObject merged into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way for a more orthodox approach:

```js
existingData = {"School Name" : "Albert"};
newData = {"Teacher Name" : "Ms. Mithcell"};

var new_keys = Object.keys(newData);

for (var i = 0; i < new_keys.length; i++){
  existingData[new_keys] = newData[new_keys[i]];
}

console.log(existingData);
```